# XML Load file inputting wrong data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, load

This is the XML schema I'm trying to script into the database. It has worked adding the details but it is not inputting the exact data, and I'm confused about what is going on.

```
<Questions>
    <Question>
      <Text>Q1. How do you consider your overall health in general?</Text>
      <QuestionID>qu_008</QuestionID>
      <Index>2</Index>
      <Variable>Q_2</Variable>
      <FullVariable>Q_2</FullVariable>
      <QType>eqtAmerican</QType>
      <AnsweredTimeStamp>2020-11-16T10:52:15Z</AnsweredTimeStamp>
      <QuestionAnswer>Very healthy</QuestionAnswer>
      <Answers>
        <Answer>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Text>Very healthy</Text>
          <Index>1</Index>
          <AnswerID>0</AnswerID>
          <Code>1</Code>
          <AnswerShortID>an_008_001</AnswerShortID>
          <AnswerVariable>A_Q_2_1</AnswerVariable>
          <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
        </Answer>
      </Answers>
    </Question>
    <Question>
      <Text>Q2. How often would you say that you..?</Text>
      <QuestionID>qu_009</QuestionID>
      <Index>3</Index>
      <Variable>Q_3</Variable>
      <FullVariable>Q_3</FullVariable>
      <QType>eqtMultiTopics</QType>
      <AnsweredTimeStamp>2020-11-16T10:55:33Z</AnsweredTimeStamp>
      <Topics>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Smoke</Text>
          <Index>1</Index>
          <TopicID>0</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>Never</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_001</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_1</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>Never</Text>
              <Index>5</Index>
              <AnswerID>4</AnswerID>
              <Code>5</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_005</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_5</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Take medicines prescribed by a doctor</Text>
          <Index>5</Index>
          <TopicID>4</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>Very little/ occasionally</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_005</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_5</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>Very little/ occasionally</Text>
              <Index>4</Index>
              <AnswerID>3</AnswerID>
              <Code>4</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_004</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_4</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Concern about the prices of healthy foods</Text>
          <Index>8</Index>
          <TopicID>7</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>A lot/ Very often</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_008</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_8</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>A lot/ Very often</Text>
              <Index>1</Index>
              <AnswerID>0</AnswerID>
              <Code>1</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_001</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_1</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Control the portions you eat (counting calories)</Text>
          <Index>9</Index>
          <TopicID>8</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>A lot/ Very often</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_009</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_9</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>A lot/ Very often</Text>
              <Index>1</Index>
              <AnswerID>0</AnswerID>
              <Code>1</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_001</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_1</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Read labels/nutritional information on products</Text>
          <Index>10</Index>
          <TopicID>9</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>A little/Sometimes</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_010</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_10</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>A little/Sometimes</Text>
              <Index>3</Index>
              <AnswerID>2</AnswerID>
              <Code>3</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_003</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_3</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
        <Topic>
          <Text>Concern about healthy living</Text>
          <Index>11</Index>
          <TopicID>10</TopicID>
          <TopicAnswer>Very little/ occasionally</TopicAnswer>
          <TopicShortID>tp_009_011</TopicShortID>
          <TopicVariable>T_Q_3_11</TopicVariable>
          <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
          <Answers>
            <Answer>
              <IsOtherSpec>False</IsOtherSpec>
              <Text>Very little/ occasionally</Text>
              <Index>4</Index>
              <AnswerID>3</AnswerID>
              <Code>4</Code>
              <AnswerShortID>an_009_004</AnswerShortID>
              <AnswerVariable>A_Q_3_4</AnswerVariable>
              <DesignTimeFlags>None</DesignTimeFlags>
            </Answer>
          </Answers>
        </Topic>
      </Topics>
    </Question>
</Questions>
```

I derived this as the standard SQL Schema from the XML for this particular table.

```
CREATE TABLE `surveyapp`.`question` (
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Text VARCHAR(500),
   QuestionID VARCHAR(100),
   Indexsur INT,
   Variable VARCHAR(100),
   FullVariable VARCHAR(100),
   QType VARCHAR(100),
   AnsweredTimeStamp TIMESTAMP,
   QuestionAnswer VARCHAR(100),
   Topic VARCHAR(100),
   AnswersID INT, 
   ChapterID INT
) CHARSET utf8mb4 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'm using the XML loader to load the file into the database. What I noticed is that it's not doing it rightly. As an example when it is supposed to use the question text it is adding a different thing entirely. I have troubleshot it but could not discover what the problem is.
[image: What is added by the XML load script]

This is the XML load data I'm using

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\MyUser\\MyUser\\Documents\\SurveyData\\SurveyData.xml'
  INTO TABLE Question
  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Question>'
  (@Text, @QuestionID, @Variable, @FullVariable, @QType, @AnsweredTimeStamp, @QuestionAnswer, @Topic, @AnswersID, @Index, @ChapterID)
  SET Text=@Text, QuestionID=@QuestionID, Variable=@Variable, FullVariable=@FullVariable, QType=@QType, AnsweredTimeStamp=@AnsweredTimeStamp, QuestionAnswer=@QuestionAnswer, Indexsur=@Index, Topic=@Topic, AnswersID=@AnswersID, ChapterID=@ChapterID;
```

Comment: Putting this in comments since I'm not sure how relevant it will be... I noticed that the date/time format in your XML does not conform to the format shown in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) for TIMESTAMP. Also, not sure if it matters (as I am new to MySQL), but your field order in your SET statement does not match the field order specified in the line above it.

Comment: I actually figured out what the problem is. I noticed it's like there are multiple <Text> tags within a <Question> tag. So the second overrides the first. Is there a way I can handle this problem? But I believe it shouldn't be doing so because the other is a subtag of the <Answer> tag. I wonder why this anomaly.

Comment: If your rows are identified by '<Question>', then multiple '<Text>' tags will be seen as duplicate column names. The obvious solution would be to modify your XML to remove the duplicate tags, or combine them before inserting them using LOAD XML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the contributions. I was able to resolve it by using this code. The unfortunate thing is that I forgot to note where I got this answer from on SO. it worked perfectly.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\GEGE\\Documents\\SurveyData\\SurveyDataText.xml'  INTO TABLE  question  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
  LINES STARTING BY '<Question>' TERMINATED BY '</Question>'
    (@tmp) SET
    -- id      = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//id'),
    Text = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Text'),
    QuestionID = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//QuestionID'),
    Variable = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Variable'),
    FullVariable = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//FullVariable'),
    QType = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//QType'),
    AnsweredTimeStamp = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//AnsweredTimeStamp'),
    QuestionAnswer = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//QuestionAnswer'),
    Topic = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Topic'),
    AnswersID = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//AnswersID'),
    Indexsur = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//Index'),
    ChapterID = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//ChapterID');
```